# How to set variant outline and size small in NumberFormat component of Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I've tried to pass `customInput={<TextField size="small" variant="outlined"/>}` component, but when I pass it that way the currency mask stops working. The way it's being shown in the Material UI documentation is kind of unclear.

```
import NumberFormat from 'react-number-format';
import { useFormikContext } from 'formik';
import TextField from '@material-ui/core/TextField';
    
export function TextFieldMoney({ name, label, disabled, maxLength }: TextFieldMoneyProps) {
  const { setFieldValue, values } = useFormikContext<any>();

  const handleChange = (event: any) => {
    setFieldValue(name, event.value)
  }

  return (
    <NumberFormat
      isNumericString={true}
      thousandSeparator={','}
      decimalSeparator={'.'}
      prefix={'R$ '}
      decimalScale={2}
      fixedDecimalScale={true}
      customInput={TextField}
      onValueChange={(value: any) => handleChange(value)}
      type="text"
    />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to pass them as props to `NumberFormat` component, for online example check [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-set-variant-outline-and-size-small-in-numberformat-component-of-material-ui-n9q7g?file=/src/App.js:355-399).

```
<NumberFormat
    isNumericString={true}
    thousandSeparator={','}
    decimalSeparator={'.'}
    prefix={'R$ '}
    decimalScale={2}
    fixedDecimalScale={true}
    customInput={TextField}
    onValueChange={(value: any) => handleChange(value)}
    variant="outlined"
    size="small"
    type="text"
/>
```